# Fastest way to generate long strings in JavaScript (performance)

Tags: javascript, string, performance, random, generator

There are lot of random string questions on stack exchange, but they do not help me with my problem.
I need to generate a lot of random (no need to be true random) long strings (256 chars) in JavaScript as fastest as possible. It doesn't need to be one-line function, performance is the only thing that matters. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: how many do you need to make in how long? 256 is quite short, but are there a million you need to make? what characters will be in the strings? anything UTF-8 at all? just ascii? just letters?

Comment: is 100000 such strings in under a second fast enough? `var str = Array.from({length:256}, () => String.fromCharCode((Math.random() * 94 + 33) | 0)).join('');`

Comment: that's a good one liner!